# Выгрузка статистики матрицы расстояний по api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-static-maps-api

нужно выгружать статистику по api как в csv на скрине, в документации не нашел. Может кто сталкивался[image: скин]

Comment: Сейчас у кабинета разработчика такой возможности нет.